# NSURLCache returning nil when trying to access cached request from disk

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, caching, afnetworking

I am trying to use the disk based url cacing built in to iOS 5. I have a json feed which i want to load and then cache, so its instantly loaded the next time a user uses the app. 
The cache.db file is successfully created and if i open it in a sqlite-editor i can fetch out the data.

I am using AFNetworking

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSLog(@"%d before call",[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage]);  // logs 0 bytes
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
// is successfully loading JSON and reading it to a table view in a view
}failure:nil];

NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request] 
// this returns nil, and can't load the request from disk.
```

In the cache response block, strangely the cache is now working, and successfully gets the cacheurl request from memory.

```
[operation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
        NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse_ = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
        NSLog(@"%d AFTER CACHE",[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage]);
        // this writes out 61440
        return cachedResponse;
    }];
```

How can i load the cached URL request from disk the next time i start the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to fetch the cached response in your first code section (line 9), the request has not completed yet.

`-[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:]` is asynchronous, so nothing will be stored in the cache until the request completes. If you try to fetch the cached response inside the success block (or in a cache response block, as you did in your second code section), it should work correctly.

As to your second question, you can't guarantee that the data will be cached by NSURLCache, even if your Cache-Control headers state that your content shouldn't expire until far in the future. The cache file is always stored in your app's Caches directory, which [can be cleared by iOS at any time](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) if it thinks it needs to free up disk space.

If you need to make sure your JSON data is always available, save it yourself in your app's `Library/Application Support` directory, ideally [with the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` specified](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342) (unless your app truly cannot function without the data).

Comment: So you're saying [NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cannot be stored on disk?

Comment: No, it can be (and usually is) stored on disk, but it is always placed in the `Caches` directory, which may be cleared by iOS at any time. The [iOS File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) enumerates the directories available in your app's sandbox and the rules that apply to each.

Comment: Yes, its stored in Cache.db and not cleared when i restart the app. So it should be able to load the cache.